# Unable to install mono on Fedora 29

Tags: fedora, software-installation, mono

I followed the instructions found at mono-project.com, I successfully installed `mono-devel` but when I try to install `mono-complete` by running `sudo dnf install mono-complete` it just says:

```
Error: Unable to find a match.
```

Same happens when I try to install `referenceassemblies-pcl`, which is also recommended by the mono project.

I'm running Fedora 29.

Comment: What instructions did you follow? Exactly what did you do?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to search for it? with `sudo dnf search mono-complete`?
I could be that it was renamed

The package  referenceassemblies-pcl is absent in the following repositories https://repology.org/project/referenceassemblies-pcl/versions

for the `mono-complete` package you could try this [Github-Can't install Mono from Mono repo for Fedora 29](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/11937#issuecomment-444887885)

Comment: Yeah I tried, it says "No matches found."

Comment: have you updated the respitories